# gcc build object and dependency files together

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, g++-4.7

Using gcc 4.7.2 on Ubuntu, I am compiling some source file with this command:

```
g++ -c -o obj/foo.o foo.cpp -O0 -Wall [.. lots of other args .. ]
```

That works fine and gives me a reasonable object file, `obj/foo.o`. However, if I want to also generate the dependency file at the same time:

```
g++ -c -o obj/foo.o foo.cpp -O -Wall [ .. ] -M -MD -MG -MP -MF obj/foo.dep
```

Then while I get a totally reasonable looking `obj/foo.dep`, I get an empty `obj/foo.o`. There is also no output from compilation at all. Looking at the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.4/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options), it seems that this should work:

> -MD
>       If -MD is used in conjunction with -E, any -o switch is understood to specify the
>       dependency output file (see -MF), but if used without -E, each -o is understood to
>       specify a target object file.
>
> Since -E is not implied, -MD can be used to generate a dependency output file as
>       a side-effect of the compilation process.

I am not using `-E`, so shouldn't this give me both an object file and a dependency output file? How can I determine where the problem is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `-M` and `-MG` options. From the gcc manpage:

> Passing -M to the driver implies -E, (...)

..and `-MG` requires `-M`, so you cannot keep it. This shouldn't be a problem because `-MG` is only important if generated header files are still missing, in which case you wouldn't be able to compile the code yet anyway.